# How does one create a mutable copy of an immutable array in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Now that Swift's Array's are truly immutable thanks to full value semantics, how can I create an mutable copy of an immutable array? Similar to Obj-C `mutableCopy()`. I can of course downcast the array to an NSArray and use `mutableCopy()` but don't want to use NSArray because it does not strictly typed.

I have a `toolbar` which has `items` from the storyboard. I want to remove an item from the toolbar and use `toolbar.setItems`. I wanted to do it without casting as a `NSArray`, because none of these functions take `NSArrays`, they take `[AnyObject]`.

Obviously now when I call `removeAtIndex()` it does not work, which is correct. I just need a mutableCopy

Simply assigning to var does not work for me and give '`Immutable value of type [AnyObject]`'

```
var toolbarItems = self.toolbar.items
toolbarItems.removeAtIndex(2) //Immutable value of type [AnyObject]
```

I am using Beta 3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that `self.toolbar.items` is an implicitly unwrapped optional (of type [AnyObject]!) and they are always immutable. When you assign to the variable `toolbarItems` without explicitly stating its type, it too becomes an implicitly unwrapped optional, and thus is immutable as well.

To fix this do either:

```
var toolbarItems:[AnyObject] = self.toolbar.items
toolbarItems.removeAtIndex(2)
```

Or:

```
var toolbarItems = self.toolbar.items as [AnyObject]
toolbarItems.removeAtIndex(2)
```

**Update**

As of Xcode 6 Beta 5, you can update collections that are stored in optional variables, so the original code now works:

```
var toolbarItems = self.toolbar.items
toolbarItems.removeAtIndex(2)
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I said in my answer, but with a concise explanation of what's under the hood - hence you deserve my upvote

Answer (score 13):

Arrays are value types (struct), so they are passed around by value and not by reference.

That said, if you create a variable of array type and assign it the immutable array, a copy of the immutable array is actually created and assigned to it - and of course that copy has no relationship with the original immutable array (besides having the same values at the time it is created).

```
let immutable = [1, 2, 3]

//immutable[0] = 1 // Fails, ok

var mutable = immutable

mutable[0] = 5
```

In your case, you are accessing an immutable array which is an `NSArray` of `AnyObject`s (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIToolbar/items)). You can use it as an Array in swift, make a copy of it and modify as follows:

```
let immutable : NSArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

//immutable[0] = 1 // Fails, ok

var mutable : [AnyObject] = immutable

mutable.removeAtIndex(1) // mutable now is [1, 3]

mutable[0] = 7 // mutable now is [7, 3]
```

After you're done with your changes, you can assign to the `items` property

Comment: This does not work for me I think because of beta 3?: 
`var toolbarItems = self.toolbar.items;toolbarItems.removeAtIndex(2)` `//Immutable value of type '[AnyObject]' Added Edit to question.

Comment: I think the problem is because `self.toolbar.items` is an `NSArray`. Looking into it

Comment: Perhaps with an NSArray, you need to go a little more old-school? Try `var mutable = immutable.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Read addition to my answer above

Comment: Aha. So typing it as a `[AnyObject]` did it.

Comment: instead of using direct array, we can also use Userdefalt() values as "immutable" Nsarray here.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as declaring a `var` with your array.

```
var items = toolbar.items
```

Now you can change items and then reassign to the toolbar.

```
toolbar.items = items
```

Note that you <strike>can</strike> cannot (as of Beta 3) alter the elements of an "immutable" array declared with `let` as well. Just the length of the array <strike>is</strike> was fixed, which is why you cannot remove items.

However, according to Apple's documentation of `UIToolbar`, the `items` array is already mutable.

> SWIFT
>   `var items: [AnyObject]!`

Comment: See my edit. I am not sure if this is because of Beta 3?

Comment: Your latest edit (with `var b = a`) works fine in Xcode build 6A254o. If you try `a[1] = 5` you will see that `b` is altered as expected.

Comment: yah I am dumbo I didn't mean to type that. I removed it. That does work but for some reason `self.toolbar.items` is still immutable. And I think that arrays now are completely immutable if you assign them. From the apple release notes: "Array in Swift has been completely redesigned to have full value semantics like Dictionary and 
String have always had in Swift.  This resolves various mutability problems – now a 'let' array 
is completely immutable, and a 'var' array is completely mutable"

Comment: @Mundi, I think that is no longer valid in beta 3, they fixed it. You cannot change the value of an element in an immutable array

Comment: See my additional answer - I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Tested + works:

```
    var mutable : [UIBarButtonItem] = []
    for button in toolbar.items {
        mutable += button as UIBarButtonItem
    }
    mutable.removeAtIndex(2)
    toolbar.setItems(mutable, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

TO REMOVE AN OBJECT FROM PARTICULAR INDEX OF AN ARRAY.

```
let fullArray : NSArray = Userdefaults().value(forKey: "YOUR_ARRAY_STRING") as! NSArray
var mutableArray : [AnyObject] = fullArray as [AnyObject]
mutableArray.remove(at: INDEX_TO_REMOVE) //Eg: mutableArray.remove(at: 0)
mutableArray.append(ARRAY_TO_APPEND)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Beta3 constant arrays are completely immutable while variable arrays are entirely mutable. So just change let array:to var array: and then verify your code