# Modifying dictionary property inside of array of dictionaries. Error: Cannot assign to immutable expression of type [String:AnyObject]

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

There are several posts on SO [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721555/how-does-one-create-a-mutable-copy-of-an-immutable-array-in-swift), and the only solution suggested that would seem to work is manually removing and inserting a property at the same index.

But this feels messy, and some posts suggest it's possible in Xcode 7 to directly update dictionary properties if inside an array of dictionaries.

However, it's not working for the code below, generating the `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type [String:AnyObject]` error.

```
// Class vars
var userDict = [String:AnyObject]()
var accounts = [[String:AnyObject]]()

func setHistory(index: Int, history: [String]) {
    (userDict["accounts"] as! [[String:AnyObject]])[index]["history"]! = history
    (userDict["accounts"] as! [[String:AnyObject]])[index]["history"] = history
    userDict["accounts"][index]["history"] = history
    userDict["accounts"][index]["history"]! = history
}
```

All four lines inside of `setHistory` try to do the same thing, and all fail.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the way you are doing this:
`userDict["accounts"] as! [[String:AnyObject]])[index]["history"]`
you are working with an immutable container.

You are going to have to design it like this:

```
func setHistory(index: Int, history: [String]) {
    //this line copies from user dict,  it is not a pointer
    var account = userDict["accounts"] as! [[String:AnyObject]];
    //this line sets the new history
    account[index]["history"] = history;
    //this line will update the dictionary with the new data
    userDict["accounts"] = account


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off with a class to model your data.

Anyhow, you can call an old friend from ObjC, `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
var userDict = [String: AnyObject]()
var accounts = [NSMutableDictionary]()

accounts.append(["history": ["history1.1", "history1.2"]])
accounts.append(["history": ["history2.1", "history2.2"]])
userDict["accounts"] = accounts

func setHistory(index: Int, history: [String]) {
    userDict["accounts"]![index].setObject(history, forKey: "history")
}

setHistory(0, history: ["history1.1", "history1.2", "history1.3"])
print(userDict)
```